# UC3845 flyback add a OVP (OVC) protection

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, protection

I built SMPS based on this schematic:
[image]

It's working nicely - I recalculated transformer and flyback to 24V, I used EI33 transformer with airgap (put 6 pieces of paper between halves of the core). I can draw continuous power (100 W) as designed. Till now good.

*Transformer details:*
EI33 core from old atx PSU, primary inductance 1,5mH. Air gap is around 0,5-0,6mm. I calculated everything with Flyback 6000 software.

[image]

Problem is, when I connect resistive load to it (12 ohm -> I=24/12=2 A) and start to decrease it to (6 ohm I=24/6=4 A) - it works, but when increased further - voltage starts to drop. When loaded more (2 ohm or less ) it goes into hiccup mode. Circuit is designed to deliver 100 W, and it does, but when it is overloaded voltage drops, and when it's overloaded more - it does hiccup.

I don't like fact that voltage drops - it will lead to misbehavior of other powered circuitry. I would like it to go into hiccup mode just when I pass let's say 4.2 A.

Why this is so important?
I use this to drive motors, and when supply is overloaded it should stop them (driver for motors) but voltage drops to ~15 V and driver has no enough power. Also hiccup protects against overheating of diode/MOSFET.

*How to implement it without compicating this ciruit too much?*

**What I tried so far:**

Adjusted auxiliary turns to make go to hiccup faster (UC3845 goes into hiccup when supply voltage is too low). I was able to lower hiccup threshold, but no much. However circuit had problem with startup - several "clicks" are very bad to my ear :)

I thought about some sort of current sensing at the output.

Schematic from here: [LINK](https://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic965524.html#gallery-6)

Comment: Why don't you lower R12 a little bit. It also sounds like 6 pieces of paper is going to be quite a large gap - any numbers? Any data sheets for the core-set? Any winding details?

Comment: Isn't lowering this resistor going to allow even larger current (lower voltage drop)?

Comment: Yes it is but hopefully it might go straight into hiccup mode without lowering the output first. Alternatively, just use a comparator to give you an "output OK" signal and make use of the not-OK signal to turn off the device (or some other action you feel more appropriate).

Comment: I lowered R2 and it only drops later, but it had no influence on hiccup "threshold". I thought about some sort comparator, but it will most likely oscillate? I mean on - off -on - off

Comment: Then you need to fix the thing that is directly causing you the problem rather than try and do something with the power supply. The power supply is secondary - if it can't supply enough power then choose a bigger supply design but, they will all pretty much do this so, look at what the real problem is and fix that.

Comment: Supply can supply enough power (100W), I just want it to go into hiccup when I overload it. Until 100W voltage is nice and stable. I can extend this "point" (100W) by lowering R2, but that's not a case. I just don't know how to force it into hiccup just after passing 100W

Comment: As far as I can tell you are trying to fix the part that doesn't need fixing. Let me ask again - what is the lack of functionality or performance of "a thing" that is causing you so much concern and don't mention the power supply in your answer - it may seem like the problem but it's secondary to the thing that causes you concern.

Comment: You are right, it shouldn't be a psu a thing that manages fault somwere else. I did not measured what actually will happed in such situation, it's just esitmation. From psu's point of view - it's normal (overload means decreasing voltage and short circuit means hiccup). I just have some sort of obsession when doing such things: "my devices should be 100% idiot-proof" or "when it claims 24V 100W it gives always 24V and when overloaded - goes into hiccup". Wouldn't the word be better when designers would think like this?

Comment: Should I leave that as an answer (and make the world a better place) or are your still hoping for a power supply fix?

Comment: This is an answer, so I see no problem. But there is another question when following: Is it okay to leave this in such state? (I'm not trying to be angry or something ) really - would it be safe to use such PSU? It has (due to uc3845) short circuit protection and overtempreature protection (added externally on thermistor). I'm not hoping for "fix" - sometimes there is no better soution. And I think I should form my quesition in different way (instead of "How to implement...") - "Is it worth/needed". Thank for Your time - I see that there is no always best solution.

Comment: In this type of simple circuit, the only protection you have is through the collapse of the auxiliary winding. Unfortunately, it depends on the leakage inductance between the power and primary windings. To implement a sharp output current cutoff, the decision must be made on the feedback and not the auxiliary \$V_{cc}\$. This is doable with the UC but it requires some additional circuitry. The hiccup would then be made by adding a small SCR across the \$V_{cc}\$ rail. The other option is to use a more modern controller such as NCP1250 or 510 which has a timer-based protection.